# Store tweets into MongoDB in RStudio

Tags: r, mongodb, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to store tweets into MongoDB in RStudio. I am getting the following errors.

```
> my_oauth<-OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret, requestURL=requestURL,accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)
> my_oauth$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve proxy: host
* Closing connection 7
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Could not resolve proxy: host
```

My system is Ubuntu 14.04. How do I solve this?

Comment: When I query the list of packages on CRAN that have "mongo" in their names I see three different interfaces to mongodb. Since you have mentioned none of them, I'm guessing (which all any of us can do in the absence of details about your db installation) that you have not done the necessary installation steps.

Comment: I ve used RMongo package

Comment: Since you later posted a question about output, I'm guessing that you figured out how to install the mongodb.

Comment: Actually both are done in two different approaches...here streamed tweets are to be stored using streamr package...There I use the search tweets function to get the tweets